# If all balls around fixed basepoints are isometric, are the spaces as well (length spaces)?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complete proper length spaces, $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Assume for every $r>0$ the closed balls $\overline{B_r(x)}$ and $\overline{B_r(y)}$ are isometric. 
Does there exist an isometry $X \to Y$?

**Remark:** If you add that the isometries between the balls all map $x$ to $y$, you get a pointed isometry between $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$.

**Definitions:** A metric space is called *proper* if all closed balls are compact. A metric space is called *length space* if the distance of two points equals the infimum of the length of curves connecting these points, i.e. $d(x,y) = \inf \{ L(c) \mid c(0) = x, c(1) = y\}$.

In fact, for a *complete length space*, this infimum is a minimum.

Comment: I feel that it would not hurt to add a definition (rather than a link) of "proper length".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO.

To get an idea look at the following picture. 
Imagine it is extended down infinitely and each segment exchanged to a thin rectangle with $\ell_\infty$-metric.

[image]

The center of the ball has to be at one of the ends.

There are ways to extend it down to get non-isometric spaces.
At one step down you have two choices --- extend it to the right $(+1)$ or to the left $(-1)$. The space can be encoded by an infinite sequence of $\pm1$. Two such spaces are isometric if the sequences coincide starting from some moment or they have opposite sign starting from some moment. In particular the space for 
$$(+1,+1,+1,+1,\dots)\ \ \text{and}\ \ (+1,-1,+1,-1,\dots)$$ 
are not isometric.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I spent some time thinking about this, but do not get it: Could you please explain how you mean to do the extensions?

Comment: @dg.jan The answer is updated.